# Apache Hudi - How to understand the hudi write operation vs spark savemode?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-hudi

How to understand the hudi write operation with `upsert` but df savemode with `append`? Since this will upsert the records, why append instead of overwrite? What's the difference?
Like showed in the pic:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `overwrite` mode, you tell spark to delete the table and recreate it (or just the partitions which exist in your new df if you use a dynamic `partitionOverwriteMode`).

But when we use `append` mode, spark will append the new data to existing old data on disk/cloud storage. With `hudi` we can provide additional operation to merge the two versions of data and update old records which have key present in new data, keep old records which have a key not present in new data and add new records having new keys. This is totally different from overwriting data.

Answer (score 0):

Example: Upsert a DataFrame, specifying the necessary field names for recordKey => _row_key, partitionPath => partition, and precombineKey => timestamp

```
inputDF.write()
   .format("org.apache.hudi")
   .options(clientOpts) //Where clientOpts is of type Map[String, String]. clientOpts can include any other options necessary.
   .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY(), "_row_key")
   .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY(), "partition")
   .option(DataSourceWriteOptions.PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY(), "timestamp")
   .option(HoodieWriteConfig.TABLE_NAME, tableName)
   .mode(SaveMode.Append)
   .save(basePath);
```

Generate some new trips, load them into a DataFrame and write the DataFrame into the Hudi table as below.

```
   // spark-shell
val inserts = convertToStringList(dataGen.generateInserts(10))
val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(inserts, 2))
df.write.format("hudi").
  options(getQuickstartWriteConfigs).
  option(PRECOMBINE_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "ts").
  option(RECORDKEY_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "uuid").
  option(PARTITIONPATH_FIELD_OPT_KEY, "partitionpath").
  option(TABLE_NAME, tableName).
  mode(Overwrite).
  save(basePath)
```

Comment: Sorry, still don't get this